# SAML message intended destination endpoint did not match the recipient endpoint

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I am trying to integrate SAML SSO with my application and I am facing below issue can someone help me out.. these are the things getting printed in logs:-

INFO o.o.c.b.s.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule - SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing

SAML message intended destination endpoint

`https://{ServerName}/Prod/sso/saml/SSO/alias/abc:def:dev:10888`

did not match the recipient endpoint

```
https://{ServerName}/sso/saml/SSO/alias/abc:def:dev:10888
```

Can some one please point out whats wrong causing such error to occur?

Comment: You should give some more information, i.e. show some code. I'm afraid right now there is not really a good way to answer this.

Comment: Hi Thomas can you please specify what else do you need?
As you can see "/Prod" is not there in recipient URL

https://{ServerName}/Prod/sso/saml/SSO/alias/abc:def:dev:10888' did not match the recipient endpoint 'https://{ServerName}/sso/saml/SSO/alias/abc:def:dev:10888

Comment: Do you have some code you could show? That would maybe help. Or can you show how you integrated SAML into your application, and how you configured the endpoints?

Comment: Yes you may see the code in below Link:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml